# How can I change the background color while hover in ContextMenu?

Tags: wpf, .net-core

Here is the default ControlTemplate of ContextMenu in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/contextmenu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-6.0

I change it like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope"
          Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow"
          Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Margin="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="2">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" BlurRadius="10" Direction="-90" Opacity="0.3"
                              RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="2" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                      KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now I met a problem, when I hover into the item, even if it is a TextBlock like this:

```
<Grid.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu>
      <TextBlock>123</TextBlock>
  </ContextMenu>
</Grid.ContextMenu>
```

[image]

It always changes its background to blue as the image above.

What's wrong with it? I want to change the background to my favorite color while I hover it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to (entirely) re-template the `MenuItem` in the `ContextMenu`, e.g.:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}">
                            <Grid Margin="-1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3"/>
                                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" Visibility="Hidden" Height="22" Width="22" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="#3D26A0DA" BorderBrush="#3D26A0DA"
                                                    BorderThickness="1" ClipToBounds="false" Margin="-1,0,0,0">
                                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1 M 10.0,1.2 L 4.7,9.1 L 4.5,9.1 L 0,5.2 L 1.3,3.5 L 4.3,6.1L 8.3,0 L 10.0,1.2 Z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"
                                          Fill="#FF212121"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="true" Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Text="{TemplateBinding MenuItem.InputGestureText}"
                                           Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.7"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Value="{x:Null}" Property="MenuItem.Icon">
                                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="GlyphPanel" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Value="LightGray" Property="Border.Background"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Red" Property="Border.BorderBrush"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
    <TextBlock>123</TextBlock>
</ContextMenu>
```